# WIll my furniture fit through a corridor and door?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I'm moving from my place and I looked at a really nice apartment. I'm trying to figure out if my table and bed will fit through the corridor and into the rooms.

The bed needs to fit in the orange room, and the table to one of the blue rooms. I'm trying to figure out what calculation will help me determine if this is a possible maneuver.

I don't currently know the width of the corridor and the enterance to the corridor, but I'll be there Friday and will be able to verify, or if any other information is needed, I'll be able to supply it come Friday.

Any help on the matter would be very appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What if the answer is "No"?  Usually, the solution to this problem is not to determine if it is going to fit, but how much you can break it down in order to *make* it fit.  Most beds and tables can be disassembled so that they can fit through smaller spaces.

Comment: How tall are the doors? The table will easily fit stood on its end (the tabletop is smaller than the door itself), and the bed might with a big enough door.

Comment: @XanderHenderson The bed can be broken into the entire base, the head and the legs. What I drew is only the base since it's the largest part. Same goes for the table but it's the skeleton of the table. It's the skeleton and the top aprat.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I don't know exactly how tall are the doors, but I believe around 190cm. I haven't really thought about it that way, so I will definitely try it out on Friday. Much thanks on this!
The bed however will most definitely won't fit standing upright.

Comment: Standing furniture on end is often the way to get it through the door, but often overlooked. Bring the bed to the end of the hall stood on its end, then lay it on its side so it goes through both doors.